# Debian Harddrive Fdisk - Same ID's and changing letters

Tags: debian, ntfs, nas

I am trying to create and install a debain NAS and ive been having a hard time because I am new to all of this. I used ntfs-3g in order to automount my 4 NTFS drives. I also have a partitioned harddrive which is for the OS.

When I was working on it and I ran this command I got this:

**fdisk -l**

- /dev/sdae1

**fdisk -l | grep NTFS**

- /dev/sda1
- /dev/sdb1
- /dev/sdc1
- /dev/sdd1

The weird thing is, all of the NTFS harddrives listed had an ID of 7.

The next time I boot up my machine, I get an error about mounting /dev/sda1 and I run this command, and get the following results:

**fdisk -l | grep NTFS**

- /dev/sdb1
- /dev/sdc1
- /dev/sdd1
- /dev/sde1

I havent plugged in any drives, so whats going on? How to I make sure that my drives are mounted with the same sdXX name every time, and is the reason for this because they dont have unique ID numbers, if so, how do I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You should use [UUID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier)s for each of the NTFS partitions, and put it in [/etc/fstab](http://wiki.debian.org/fstab).